# Как регулировать нагрузку на процессор с помощью javascript?

Tags: javascript, highload, препроцессор

Как регулировать нагрузку на процессор с помощью javascript. Или вобще есть какой-то метод для получения доступа к информации цп или взаимодействие с ним.

Comment: А вы интересуетесь из браузерного окружения или через `node.js`?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko - браузера

Comment: никак ты из браузера не получишь данные по ЦП, это небезопасно и ни один браузер тебе эти данные не отдаст, поскольку сам не имеет к ним доступ

Comment: А каким обрязом можно это сделать?

Comment: А зачем? Какая цель ставится?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov  Мне просто интересно как это делается. Вот например на сайтах с браузерным майнингом там можно регулировать нагрузку цп.

Comment: А вот регулировать нагрузку - это совсем другой вопрос! Там все проще может быть, например майнить не все 100% времени, а 50% времени, вот вам и будет 50% загрузка CPU.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, интересная мысль такты на js, ещё можно вспомнить `web workers`

Comment: Ох уж эти майнеры браузерные!

Comment: @qwabra `web workers` по любому нужны. Или даже лучше `service workers`, что бы продолжать майнить, даже когда вкладка закрыта!